# Determine if a specific number is -gonal

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, summation

I am currently working with -gonal numbers (pentagonal, hexagonal, pentagonal) and I have run into a bit of an issue. Currently, if I want to know the nth -gonal number I can work that out. For example, If I wanted to know the nth heptagonal number I would be able to find it by:
$ \sum (5i - 4)$

I am unsure on how to extrapolate on what I know to find out if a specific number is a -gonal number. For example, if I wanted to know if 4567 is a heptagonal number, I am not sure where to solve for this other than just find all the -gonal numbers until I surpass the one i'm looking for, which I imagine to be way too time consuming.

My work:

I know a triangle is $\sum (i)$ and I know that we can solve that by the formula $(n(n+1))/2$ and I tried substituting in $(5i - 4)$ for the sum formula, but that didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For constants $a,b$ you have

$$\sum_{i=1}^n ai+b = a \sum_{i=1}^n i + b \sum_{i=1}^n 1 = \frac{a n(n+1)}{2} + bn.$$

You can set this equal to your given number and solve for $n$; if you get an integer then your given number was whatever-gonal.

I'm not sure if this *fully* answers your question, since I'm not that closely familiar with the -gonal numbers.

Comment: Thank you so much, that makes a lot of sense. Just a question though: how did you get the  $ \sum ai + b $ is that from some rule/law/math-thingy? 

Sorry if I am a bit dense, I struggle a bit with math.

Comment: @Nickknack Well for instance the pentagonal numbers are those of the form $\sum_{i=1}^n 5i-4$ for some integer $n$. I'm not sure whether all the -gonal numbers are of these forms, though.

Comment: Each of the -gonal numbers I am working with are in some sum formation like that. I'm just wondering where you derived the: ∑i=1nai+b=a∑i=1ni+b∑i=1n1=an(n+1)2+bn
from. It's probably really obvious and I'm just overlooking it.

Comment: @Nickknack Oh, I just factored the $a,b$ out of the summation, then used the formula $\sum_{i=1}^n i = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$. The sum $\sum_{i=1}^n 1 = n$ is trivial.

Answer (score 1):

You're talking about [Polygonal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygonal_number).

The $n$-th $s$-gonal number is
$$
\frac{n^2(s-2)-n(s-4)}{2}
$$

If you have a number $N$ and want to see whether it is an $s$-gonal number, then you have to solve a quadratic equation in $n$:
$$
\frac{n^2(s-2)-n(s-4)}{2} = N
$$
You are only interested in solutions that are natural numbers:
$$
n = \frac{\sqrt{8(s-2)N+(s-4)^2}+(s-4)}{2(s-2)}.
$$

If you don't know $s$, then there is no general solution because some $s$-gonal numbers are also $t$-gonal numbers for $s\ne t$.